# dbo in SqlServer

Tags: sql-server, teradata, dbo

I'm converting database from Teradata to SqlServer. I've noticed all tables and procedures are named by the prefix "dbo." (e.g. "dbo.Table1").

I would like to know if and how I can get rid of "dbo" because it would make the conversion task a lot more easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dbo` is *not* part of the table name. It is the name of the schema that the tables and stored procedures are attached to. `dbo` is the default schema in SQL server, though you can add others if needed.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190387.aspx) MSDN article about them.

Answer (score 4):

dbo is the schema, you can specify a new schema if you like. dbo is default is sql server.

Answer (score 2):

All tables have to go into a schema. As durilai says, dbo is the "default" schema for SQL Server (it always exists). However, note that different users can have different default schemas (if more than one exists).

If you make reference to a table without specifying the schema, then SQL Server will search in your default schema for it (and the same goes for any other objects).

So, *if* your default schema is dbo, the following two statements are equivalent:

```
select * from Table1
select * from dbo.Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

dbo is the default schema in SQL Server if no schema was set by user,
if you want you can create new schema and create tables to it.

Answer (score 0):

Schemas are useful. For example, I used to grant an app login execute permission to every stored procedure separately.  Now I grant the app login execute permission to the schema that contains all the stored procedures.  This is much easier.